# how do i get http header values from a post request

Tags: asp.net, post, httpwebrequest, http-headers

See what I'm trynig to do is on a post request made collect the http headers and then add them to app.Request.Headers.Add().

In my application basically another post request overides certain post requests that I make.

On each request to my server there is a redirection to another server which adds some headers over my original post request

I need some way of saying maybe ok add these headers but then execute my post request with its headers after

Comment: Could you tag this question with the platform you are using, e.g. asp.net ?